# Mapping two classes on Single Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's I have table

**USER**
*-id : long

-login : varchar

-weapon: varchar

-magic: varchar*

And I want map this Table on two classes (using Hibernate/JPA)

```
class Mag  
{   
   long id;  
   String login;  
   String weapon;  
}
```

and

```
class Warrior  
{  
   long id;  
   String login;  
   String magic;  
}
```

And if I send HQL query : `SELECT m FROM Mag m WHERE m.login = ?` then I get Mag instance
and if I send HQL query : `SELECT w FROM Warrior w WHERE w.login = ?` then I get Warrior instance
I try make something like this

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "User")  
class User   
{  
   long id;  
   String login;  
}  

@Entity  
class Mag extends User  
{  
   String magic;  
}  

@Entity  
class Warrior extends User   
{  
   String weapon;  
}
```

But @Inheritance requared discriminator column, but I haven't discriminator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for [MappedSuperClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html), which allows the subclasses to inherit the annotations from the superclass without needing a discriminator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Discriminator for this,if you have a deliminator column. Assume you deliminator column is

> utype char(1)

And if

> utype = m, that is a Mag entity and
>
> utype=w,  that is Warrior entity

Please find code bellow.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "utype", discriminatorType =  DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@Table(name = "User")  
class User   
{  
   long id;  
   String login;  
}  

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("m")  
class Mag extends User  
{  
   String magic;  
}  

@Entity  
@DiscriminatorValue("w")  
class Warrior extends User   
{  
   String weapon;  
}
```